# TeXShop cannot print hello world

Tags: errors, environments, texshop

I'm running TeXShop on a mac. My latex environment somehow has somehow stopped working and can no longer even print hello world.
Here's my complete latex document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   Hello world!
\end{document}
```

which gives the following error:

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7)
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MyThesis.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \begin
          {document}
? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] 
)</usr/local/texlive/2008basic/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/bluesky/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on MyThesis.pdf (1 page, 6895 bytes).
SyncTeX written on MyThesis.synctex.gz
Transcript written on MyThesis.log.
```

How do I start to debug this?

Comment: you are using pdftex you need pdf **la** tex

Comment: Great, how do I tell TexShop to switch? 
My TexShop settings:
http://postimg.org/image/v25wrkekf/ and http://postimg.org/image/8l07u4zpv/
I have binaries /usr/texbin/pdftex and /usr/texbin/pdflatex.

Comment: @Schroeder The main TeXshop windows has a dropdown next to the 'Typeset' button which should say 'LaTeX' (or similar), rather than 'Plain TeX'.

Answer (score 1):

TeXShop will let you choose between typesetting using LaTeX and using plain TeX: the error suggests you are doing the latter. The main TeXshop windows has a dropdown next to the 'Typeset' button which should say 'LaTeX' (or similar), rather than 'Plain TeX'. Alter the setting and try again.

Comment: To make the change permanent, do it in the TeXShop Preferences: select the 'Typesetting' panel from the top bar of the Preferences window, and check the buttons 'LaTeX' under Default Command and 'Pdftex' under Default Script. This combination gives pdflatex from then on.